# MYSQL QUERY combining two queries

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey how can I combine the two queries below into one?? so I get the result set as one becuase the first query is getting the points results from a table and the table below is getting the rest that I need from another table, but there both related to eachother as when the first query is excuted is could do the secound query with it. I just don't know how? any help is great.

```
SELECT t.team_id, t.teamname, t.code, t.value, 
  SUM(Case When track_id = (SELECT MAX(track_id) FROM team_stats) Then points Else 0 End) lastracepoints,
    SUM(points) AS points
FROM team_stats ts                
    Left Join teams t
    on t.team_id = ts.team_id
    GROUP BY ts.team_id 


   SELECT SUM(IF(qual_pos = '1', 1,0)) AS poles,
   SUM(IF(race_pos <= '3', 1,0)) AS podiums,
   SUM(IF(race_pos = '1', 1,0)) AS victories,
   SUM(overtakes) AS overtakes
   FROM driver_stats s
   left join drivers d
   on d.drivers_id = s.drivers_id
   GROUP by d.team_id
```

Comment: Edit your question to show how you'd like the resultset to be shaped. i.e. vertically or horizontally?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) options of mysql can help you out here.